# How to create an android app for live streaming from an IP camera connected on the local area network?

Tags: android, video, header, rtsp

I am using [EasyVideoLibrary](http://I%20am%20using%20https://github.com/afollestad/easy-video-player) since i got multiple cameras to monitor. Here the problem is i cant stream videos which has header/authentication tokens in it.
eg: rtsp://admin:admin@/192.0.0.0:500/12

I cant stream the above link as EasyVideoLibrary is not providing method to pass header along with the url.
Is there any way to customize the library? Looking forward for the solution.Below is my adapter code.

```
public class VideoAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<VideoAdapter.VewHolder>
    implements EasyVideoCallback, EasyVideoProgressCallback {

Context mContext;
List<String> cameraList;

public VideoAdapter(Context mContext, List<String> cameraList) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.cameraList = cameraList;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public VideoAdapter.VewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.camera_adapter, parent, false);
    return new VewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull VideoAdapter.VewHolder holder, int position) {
    assert holder.player != null;
    holder.player.setCallback(this);
    holder.player.setProgressCallback(this);
    holder.player.setSource(Uri.parse(cameraList.get(position)));
    holder.player.setAutoPlay(true);
    holder.player.setLoop(false);
    holder.player.enableControls(true);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return cameraList.size();
}

@Override
public void onVideoProgressUpdate(int position, int duration) {

}

@Override
public void onStarted(EasyVideoPlayer player) {

}

@Override
public void onPaused(EasyVideoPlayer player) {

}

@Override
public void onPreparing(EasyVideoPlayer player) {

}

@Override
public void onPrepared(EasyVideoPlayer player) {
    player.start();
}

@Override
public void onBuffering(int percent) {

}

@Override
public void onError(EasyVideoPlayer player, Exception e) {

}

@Override
public void onCompletion(EasyVideoPlayer player) {
    player.release();
}

@Override
public void onRetry(EasyVideoPlayer player, Uri source) {

}

@Override
public void onSubmit(EasyVideoPlayer player, Uri source) {

}

@Override
public void onClickVideoFrame(EasyVideoPlayer player) {

}

public class VewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    EasyVideoPlayer player;

    public VewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        player = itemView.findViewById(R.id.player);
    }
}}
```